# How to custom error page with htacess

Tags: apache

I've an issue with my *.htacess* file. It works fine at localhost but nothing online. When I put a false URL to check, it returns to *index.php*

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Confirm with your online provider that they process `.htaccess` files.  Then make sure your `.htaccess` is in the root folder or your site.

Comment: thanks for your reply. That's what  i did before i ask the question. They talk about create a folder at root and then put inside the website. I did this but whatever i do the false link returns a homepage. My be i have to make a php file with redirect.

Comment: Some providers do not process .htaccess.  Last weekend, I had to build a PHP page with redirect since 1and1 did not run my htaccess (even though they say they should).

Comment: Yes i think this is the only way too.

Comment: This might also be a simple caching issue. Don't always blame the provider that fast. They know whether they support dynamic configuration files or not. In all cases I saw so far it was not once the fault of the provider when things did not work as expected.